# PHP Session files not readeble

Tags: php, session

I'm experiencing a problem related to php *sess_* files.

In our development environment, we have *sess_* files accesibles and content:

> boRegister|b:1;svIdUsuario|s:1:"1";boUsuarioSistema|b:1;

The same application in a production environment, we have sess_ files content like

> KTkxG_TKqVeI4evDDbR6URAy9Xpj6REgeTQ5hozoMzggmWhScEtIcAwFBMU_JN1WAsrDNeQpABgO0dfHtm-xCNpDGrcwI .....

Application in production environment is managing php sessions ok, but we need to access to another users session data and with this environment session_decode does not work.

Any idea about this *sess_* files content codification?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: This does not seem like a good idea. I have to wonder what your use-case for requiring this is.

Comment: Is saving session in database an option?

Comment: Yep it can be @Rahi if you want to keep an eye which session has been there at what time.

Comment: Sessions are saved in files sess_...... the only difference is just on development environment is serialized, but readable, and in production environment is not readable (is coded as KTkxG_TKqVeI4evDDbR6URAy9Xpj6REgeTQ5hozoMzggmWhScEtIcAwFBMU_JN1WAsrDNeQpABgO0dfHtm-xCNpDGrcwI .....)

Comment: Finally I've found the problem. There is a php extension (suhosin) for securing session files and it's enabled at production server.